# GitLab in one server and git in other server

Tags: git, gitlab

I have in my NAS Synology a Git Server in SSH mode. 
In my raspberry, I have installed Gitlab.

Can I connect my gitlab to my NAS ? 
And if it's possible, how can i do this ?

Thanks a lot ! 
Best regards

Comment: "connect [your] gitlab to [your] NAS" in order to do what?  There are many things that could mean

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger : 
My NAS have a service git running in port 22.
I can't have the gitlab service in my NAS because he's too old.
So I have installed the gitlab solution in my raspberry.  
When I push files..., I want the gitlab push files in my NAS.

Comment: You can a confire a repo in gitlab as mirror repository to NAS, but this is just have the same repo in different places.